# Create Local DNS Record

Tags: windows, networking, vmware, dns

I created a new VM, and was able to ping it using its IP address.  However, I can't ping it by name - even though it belongs to the same "WORKGROUP" as my other windows machines.  What makes this particularly strange is the result of the following command:

```
C:\>ping -a 192.168.0.20

Pinging WIN-AOHA8MSD3D0 [192.168.0.20] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.20: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
...
```

So the machine name can be queried, as indicated above, but when I turn around with that name it fails:

```
C:\>ping WIN-AOHA8MSD3D0
Ping request could not find host WIN-AOHA8MSD3D0. Please check the name and try
again.
```

In case it is relevant, the VM is in VMWare Workstation 7.1 using a bridged network adapter.  The guest OS is Windows 2008 R2 SP1.  The host is Windows 7 x64.  Originally the ping of the IP address had not worked either, but I had created an ICMP rule on the guest OS that allowed the echo request.

What is necessary to make the machine name "pingable?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the host, make sure **[Network Discovery](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Enable-or-disable-network-discovery)** is enabled.

On the guest (and host if necessary), configure your firewall to allow the following protocols:

- **[LLMNR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLMNR): UDP to port 5355**

  Used by Windows Vista, 7, and 2008. Uses multicast.
- **[NetBIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS#Name_service): UDP to port 137** for the [name service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS#Name_service).

  Optionally UDP/138 for NetBIOS datagrams, in order for [browsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_service) to work. Not needed for name resolution.

  Used by all Windows versions, also OS/2 and LAN Manager for MS-DOS. Uses broadcast, does not support IPv6. My recommendation is to *not* enable this if LLMNR works. On the other hand, NBNS is still better than manual /etc/hosts editing, and is supported by many operating systems (including Linux through Samba).
- Apple's **mDNS** is not part of Windows, but fairly common nevertheless and available for Windows ([Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software))) and Linux ([Avahi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_(software))), also the only officially open protocol in this list. If you decide to install it, open UDP port 5353.

If name resolution still fails, use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) to monitor the network traffic.

Comment: The network discovery piece was all that was necessary. However, I "fixed" it differently than directed by the link you provided. I went into Windows firewall advanced settings on the guest, and enabled half of the already existing inbound network discovery rules. Instantly I could access the guest by name from the host. I disabled the network discovery rules, and the host (not surprisingly) continued to access the guest by name.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to add an entry to your C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/HOSTS file.  This file is normally flagged as "Read Only" so you'll need to temporarily remove the Read-Only attribute before editing it with a plain/text editor like Windows Notepad (and don't forget to flag it as Read-Only again after completing your edits).

The line you add to the file will look like this:

- 192.168.0.20 WIN-AOHA8MSD3D0

You can add it at any line within the file (near the top, at the end, whatever you prefer).

If you're running a DNS server (such as ISC-Bind, which is available for Windows as well), then you'll need to edit the appropriate DNS zone files (one for the domain/hostname, and the other for reverse lookups which will be a subordinate of the "IN-ADDR.ARPA." zone).