# How can I rewrite URLs?

Tags: networking, ip, iptables

I am running an instance of Grafana on my machine. It is open on port 3000. But instead of having to type 1xx.x.x.x:3000 can I configure this to be my-grafana.com? I have no idea what I would even search to accomplish. Thanks to all of those who reply in advance.

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: You can accomplish this with pretty much any webserver out there, most notably Nginx or Apache.

Comment: check out this answer on superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/299503/create-local-dns-record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is called DNS hosting. 
First of all you'll need to buy your domain, my-grafana.com, (if its available) from a domain register e.g lcn.com.

This URL will need to be hosted. I use Namecheap DNS hosting, its free. In the namec. control panel create A record with host ‘@‘. Fill in the value field with your public IP address. If your ISP  changes your IP address every so often (dynamic) read more here: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/43/11/how-do-i-set-up-a-host-for-dynamic-dns. 
Leave the TTL value at 1 min.

At your router or gateway settings, you will need to configure port forward settings. Forward port 443 to port 3000 to the internal ip address of your server or PC running grafana.

Browse to https://example.com it should go to your grafana.